# Cargar productos a partir de una id de categoria, con jquerry ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

recurro a preguntar esto aquí ya que después de buscar mucho no he podido solucionar, creo que el problema esta en la importacions de jquerry ajax.
Estoy haciendo una web modelo MCU.
Este es el fichero view_categorias.php

```
    <div>
        <?php foreach($resultado_categorias as $categoria): ?>
          <ul>
             <a class="Productos" onClick="cargaProductos(<?php echo $categoria['id'];?>);"> <?php echo $categoria['nombre']; ?>
          </ul>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Aqui llamo a la funcion cargaProductos, que esta en este js

```
function cargaProductos(id){

$.ajax({url: "index.php?accio=listar-productos&categoria=" + id, success: function(result){
        $("#Productos").html(result);
    }
})
```

}

```
En el php del index tengo:

    $accio = $_GET['accio']
switch($accio) {
    case 'listar-categorias':
        include __DIR__.'/resource_llistar_categories.php';
        break;

    case 'listar-productos':
        include __DIR__.'/resource_llistar_productes.php';
        break;


    default:
        include __DIR__.'/controllers/portada.php';
        break;
}
?>
```

Y en el recurso de productos llamo al controlador donde coge la categoria, y llama al modelo, ahí hace las consultas y en el vista las imprime. 
(Si yo entro a la url especificando categoria se me cargan los productos segun la categoria).

El problema esta que cuando estoy en el listado de categorias y pulso una, no pasa nada y no se actualiza nada.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar developer tools y mirar si aparece algo en la consola?

Comment: no me aparece nada en la consola, pero en el "Network" me sale la dirección a la que debería acceder @Orici

Comment: Por favor prueba si está llamando a la función y si está pasando el `id`  realmente, poniendo algo así: `function cargaProductos(id){ alert(id); };` Y, ¿revisaste la consola de Javascript para ver si emite algún error?